# Use of "se" in "La solución se debe empezar a beber en cantidades pequeñas cada hora o 2 horas, según se vaya tolerando"

Tags: gramática, verbo-pronominal

In an article about how to deal with food poisoning, from the castellano website Hola.com, I read the following sentence:

> La solución ***se*** debe empezar a beber en cantidades pequeñas cada hora o 2 horas, según **se** vaya tolerando.

Question: Even though I understand the meaning of the sentence, could you please help to explain grammatically the use of these two "se" in the sentence? My assumptions:

1. "*La solución se debe empezar a beber*" - Here I guess either reflexive "deberse" is used or passive voice is used (...must be started to drink). I tend more towards passive...
2. "*Se vaya tolerando*" - I know the construction "ir + present progressive" for cases when you start or gradually doing something ("*Voy comprendiendo la verdad - I am starting to understand the truth*"). As for my sentence, it could mean "as you gradually tolerate more and more of the drink".

Comment: You could think of it like this: *One should start taking the solution in small amounts* or *The solution should be taken starting in small amounts*.  (I personally am not the greatest when it comes to grammar terminology, so someone else might contradict me on this -- but I do think of this as being equivalent to the passive voice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job, you are right in all your interpretations:

Both uses of *se* are passive constructions ([pasiva refleja](https://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables)). These are more convoluted then the standard examples, but both clauses are equivalent to a sentence in the passive voice:

- La solución debe empezar a *ser bebida*...
- ... segun vaya *siendo tolerada*.

In these convoluted cases, it is even more true that the constructions using *se* are more natural and idiomatic.

As you say, the clause "se vaya tolerando" uses "ir + gerundio" to mean that the solution is gradually more and more tolerated.